# Ruby if elsif else problems

Tags: ruby

Good morning all

First post and hope someone can help me out.

I am trying to create a piece of code within Ruby that does the following:

"greeting_hello(str) take the name parameter being passed to return "Hello Lori!" if the name parameter is equal to "Lori", return "Hello John!" if the name parameter is equal to "John" or "Hello!" if the name parameter is equal to any other."

```
def greeting_hello(str)
    
    str = ("")
    
    if str == "Lori"
        puts "Hello Lori!"
    elsif str == "John"
        puts "Hello John!"
    else
        puts "Hello!"
    end
    
    return str 
end
```

The output I'm getting whilst using the above code is:

```
Hello Lori!
Lori #why is this displaying?
```

or

```
Hello John!
John #same here, why is this displaying?
```

or

```
Hello! #this displays as intended if Lori or John is not input.
```

Any help or pointers appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I guess you're using `irb` to execute the code. You are printing the string using `puts` and also returning the string at the end. In `irb`, the returned value is also shown.

Comment: _"whilst using the above code"_ – how do you use the code? Post a complete example that produces output.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. The code works perfectly fine exactly as it should.

Comment: the code you posted and the symptoms you are displaying are different. See my answer below.

Comment: I encourage using `puts` everywhere you need to check the value assigned to a variable. Here, using `puts str` at the beginning of the function and before the `if` statement will explicit your error. A more advanced (and handy) approach would be to use an interactive debugger such as `byebug` or `pry`

Comment: @JohnBrookfields - After researching irb I believe you are correct and that is the environment I'm using/testing this code. I have removed the puts and still don't get the desired result.

Comment: @Shybairn You must remove the last line `return str` not the `puts`. But now replace all the `puts` with `return` (after removing `return str`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's returning the name you pass in because you're returning the str at the end of the method. So it runs through your if/else conditional and `puts` the string you want, but then you return the string at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning the `str` variable inside the `greetings_hello` function.

You take the function argument `str` then assign an empty string to it
Then you check if empty string equals `Lori` (it fails here)
Then you check if empty string equals `John` (it fails the comparison as well)
and because of that it prints out `Hello!`.
Afterwards you return `str` at the end of the function. Because `str` is `""` it just returns empty string.

What you want is to not reassign the function argument.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the feedback. I understand your comment but when I don't assign str I get the following errors:/tmp/423898769/main.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ==
  if == "Cristina"
     ^~
/tmp/423898769/main.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected `elsif', expecting `end'
  elsif == "Kay"
  ^~~~~
/tmp/423898769/main.rb:9: else without rescue is useless
  else
  ^~~~
/tmp/423898769/main.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected `end', expecting end-of-input

Comment: post your code without str reassignment - this error kinda suggest that you've have some kind of syntax error that is unrelated to the variable assignment

Comment: `def greeting_hello(str)
    
       
    if str == "Lori"
        puts "Hello Lori!"
    elsif str == "John"
        puts "Hello John!"
    else
        puts "Hello!"
    end
    
    return str 
end`
#When I remove the str reassignment like above this is how the error generates

Comment: The code you posted works without any error when I put any argument to the function call. From the stacktrace you have posted it looks like you have different things in your code ("Cristina? Kay?) so I think that you may have made a mistake on your end

Comment: You were correct. What was also causing errors was the Return str. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do?
namely: assign default value of argument and use `case` :

```
def greeting_hello(str = "")

    case str
    when "Lori"
        "Hello Lori"
    when "John"
            "hello John"
    else
        "hello"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try below code!!!

```
def greeting_hello(str)
    ["Lori", "John"].include?(str) ? "Hello #{str}!" : "Hello!"
end
```

I have used ruby ternary operator & array include method here.

Refer below three links for more details

[Ternary operator](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/10/ruby-ternary-operator/)

[Array include](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/include%3F)

[String interpolation](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html)

Comment: For a Ruby newbie that code might seem a little cryptic. You should add some explanation.

Comment: Its a ruby ternary operator
Refer this - https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/10/ruby-ternary-operator/

It is same as if else in ruby
```
str = if ["Lori", "John"].include?(str)
    "Hello #{str}!"
else
  "Hello!"
end

return str
```

Answer (score 0):

### Return Values in a REPL

There's a difference between what Ruby prints on standard output and what it returns as a value from a method or expression. That's the source of your unexpected text.

When you run code in irb, pry, or any other REPL, every Ruby expression returns a value to the console. You wouldn't see the extra output if you were running the code non-interactively (e.g. `ruby foo.rb`).

In this specific case, it's returning the value of *str* because your method ends with `return str`, so you're explicitly returning that value. It's just a little non-obvious because your REPL isn't styling it nicely. I recommend adding the following to your `~/.irbrc` to make the return values more visually intuitive:

```rb
IRB.conf[:PROMPT][:DEFAULT][:RETURN].prepend '#'
```

You are also clobbering the value passing into *str* when you set it to `""` at the top of your method definition, so there's actually no way the code you've posted is *returning* anything other than `""` regardless of what it prints on standard output. Even without the explicit return, [Kernel#puts](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) always returns nil, which is also unlikely to be what you expect to see as your return value.

### Refactoring Your Code

Replacing [Kernel#puts](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) with [Kernel#p](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-p) following will do what you expect:

```rb
# str is assigned nil if a name isn't passed as an argument
def greeting_hello(str=nil)
    if str == "Lori"
        p "Hello Lori!"
    elsif str == "John"
        p "Hello John!"
    else
        p "Hello!"
    end
end

greeting_hello 'Lori'
"Hello Lori!"
#=> "Hello Lori!"

greeting_hello 'John'
"Hello John!"
#=> "Hello John!"

greeting_hello 'Abby'
"Hello!"
#=> "Hello!"

greeting_hello
"Hello!"
#=> "Hello!"
```

If all you want to do is have a sensible return value, you can stop here.

#### A More Advanced Refactoring

A more advanced refactoring using some Ruby 3.0.0 semantics and that doesn't try to reject names other than `Lori` or `John` might look like this:

```rb
# use interpolation to increase flexibility, with a conditional space added
# after the word "Hello" if str is neither nil nor an empty string
def greeting_hello str=nil
  optional_space = ' ' unless str.nil? or str.empty?
  sprintf 'Hello%s%s!', optional_space, str
end

# test against various inputs
['Lori', 'John', 'Fred', '', nil].map { greeting_hello _1 }
#=> ["Hello Lori!", "Hello John!", "Hello Fred!", "Hello!", "Hello!"]
```

This is probably more than you need to do for resolving your current problem, but it's often helpful to know that there's always more than one way to do things in Ruby. Some of them can be pretty compact, although there's sometimes a balance to be struck between clever code and readable code. Your mileage in that regard may vary.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you for this. Just starting out as you can probably tell, but just soaking up as much information as possible. Appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

Removing Return str.

Removing str = “”

This resolved my problem.

Thanks for the support.